# Undefined method error when using Searchkick with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am trying to implement a search function on my `Rails` app to get a search box working.

However, when running the code, the following error is raised:

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#index undefined method `paginate' for #<Searchkick::Results:0x007f3ff123f0e0>
```

(I also have a tag cloud, which is working fine if I keep the code below unchanged, but if I change `@posts = @posts` to `@posts = Post.search` it breaks the tag functionality too.)

I am using:

- Rails 4.2.0
- ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]

**Code:**

Here is how my `PostsController` looks like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    else
      @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2)
    end

    if params[:nil].present?
      @posts = @posts.search(params[:nil]).paginate(page: params[:page])
    else
      @posts = @posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def autocomplete
    render json: Post.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 5).map(&:title)
  end

  private

  def find_post
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :content, :tag_list, :preview)
  end
end
```

end

This is how my navbar search form looks like

```
<li class="navs">
    <%= form_tag posts_path, method: :get do%>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:query], placeholder: "Search Blog", name: "nil" , required: "", class: "input-field", id: "post_search", autocomplete: "off" do %>
            <%= submit_tag "", class: "material-icons search-box" %>
        <% end %>
        <% if params[:search].present? %>
            <%= link_to "X", posts_path %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

I have searched a lot and couldn't find any answers specific that could give me a right direction as to what I am doing wrong.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#pagination

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `search` call will return a `Searchkick::Results` collection, rather than an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. The latter has been patched with the `paginate` method, while the former has not, thus raising a `NoMethodError`.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#pagination), you should be able to make this work by passing the pagination parameters to the `search` method:

```
@posts = @posts.search(params[:nil], page: params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to doing pagination within the SeachKick query you can just do the following in a separate step.
`@posts = Kaminari.paginate_array(@posts).page(params[:page])`